# PHP CURL POST fields

Tags: php, zend-framework

So here is the question. I'm trying to call my api with PHP CURL post like so

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        $data = array('page' => $pageid);
        $data = json_encode($data);

        $fields = 'data=' . urlencode($data);

        /*echo $fields; ## data=%7B%22page%22%3A%222%22%7D */

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.myurl.com/api/gallery');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result =curl_exec($ch);

        $products=json_decode($result,true);
?>
```

and In my API which is using zend framework, I received the data like so

```
<?php
        $data = json_decode($this->_getParam('data',''), true);
        $query = array();
        $query['status'] = '1';
        $query['pid']   = (isset($data['pid']))? $data['pid'] : '';
        $query['search'] = (isset($data['search']))? $data['search'] : '';
        $query['orderby'] = (isset($data['sort']))? $data['sort'] : 'latest';
        $query['page'] = (isset($data['page']))? $data['page'] : '1';
        $query['pagelimit'] = (isset($data['pagelimit']))? $data['pagelimit'] : '2';
?>
```

when I check the value in query, it didn't received the "page" value passed by using CURL.. Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Comment: are you sure you want to pass `?data={some:object, goes: here}`

Comment: yea I just want to keep the json format

Comment: try just passing { object }, then dump $_POST to see what you get.

Comment: just tried passing this data={"page":"4"}, not working :S

Comment: it actually passed the json when I print it out, I see like this {\"page\":2} with slash... but when I json_decode it it turn out to 0

Comment: Have you tried calling [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before decoding the JSON?

Comment: ye I am now trying to strip slash, just tried $data = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); doesn't work. But the thing is json looks fine before sending out..

Comment: OMG working now. 
$json = stripslashes($this->_getParam('data',''));$data = json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should check _getParam method that returns POST variables correctly.

Then, Note, you should use json_decode on one really json string! you should decode url data variable(result of $this->_getParam('data','')) and then pass it to json_decode!

I assume your _getParam method works correctly,
then:

```
$data = json_decode(urldecode($this->_getParam('data','')), true);
$query = array();
.
.
.
```